# Rate a YouTube Video with YouTube API (Swift)

Tags: swift, youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, alamofire

I want to be able to like a YouTube video by using the YouTube API in my iOS app. I'm using Alamofire to fire the request like so:

```
Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate", parameters: ["id":VIDEO_ID,"rating":"like","key":API_KEY], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
```

But this does not work because the API needs authorization. I was looking through YouTube's [references](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) to try to figure out how to get authorization, but I don't understand it as I am new to using APIs and the OAuth 2.0 protocol in general. Can someone help me get this done? I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: you need to authenticate using oauth2 which means you should be using google SDK to do this. Once the user has authenticated, then you will have access to all this data. You should use these docs for this instead of the Rest API.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/
 and this
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps

Answer (score 0):

Follow the OAuth Guide for Youtube API in [Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). You can see the different Oauth flows:

**OAuth 2.0 flows**

> Google APIs support several OAuth 2.0 use cases:
>
> - The server-side flow supports web applications that can securely store persistent information.
> - The client-side flow supports JavaScript applications running in a browser.
> - The installed application flow supports applications installed on a device, such as a phone or computer. The device flow supports devices
>     with limited input capabilities, such as game consoles and video
>     cameras.
> - The service account flow supports server-to-server interactions that do not access user information. However, the YouTube Data API does not
>     support this flow. Since there is no way to link a Service Account to
>     a YouTube account, attempts to authorize requests with this flow will
>     generate a NoLinkedYouTubeAccount error.

There's also the [Swift Youtube Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) for your reference.